# build win_sdk from android source - complains tools\aapt.exe missing

Tags: android

I'm building windows sdk from android source code, using:

```
make PRODUCT-<product>-win_sdk
```

A zip package is generated in dir out/host/windows/. I use 'android list target' to verify if ti works. Unfortunately it displays empty. Add a '-v' to it shows:

```
Ignoring platform 'android-2.3.7': tools\aapt.exe is missing.
```

In fact, this file is in platform-tools. I move it and many other files to platforms\android-2.3.7\tools. After that the 'list target' command shows 'android-2.3.7'. It may be OK.

Another issue still exists: the emulator halts. A -show-kernel option enables the kernel log, and it shows a kernel panic happened:

```
Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init!
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks.